# Serialize updates of ARRAY field in sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I use sequelize as ORM for a Postgres database. One of my database models looks like the following:

```js
...
Item.init(
   {
      id: {
         type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
         primaryKey: true,
         autoIncrement: true,
         allowNull: false,
      },
      name: {
         type: DataTypes.STRING,
         allowNull: false,
      },
      availableSizes: {
          type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.INTEGER),
          allowNull: false,
      }
}
...
```

Now I have an array of JSON-Objects for which I want to create database entries, e.g. the following one:

```js
items = [{name: "a", size: 1}, {name: "a", size: 2}, {name: "b", size: 1}]
```

For this array I wish to create the following database entries:

```js
{
   id: 1,
   name: "a",
   availableSizes: [1,2]
},
{
   id: 2,
   name: "b",
   availableSizes: [1]
}
```

Currently I use the following code for this:

```js
items.forEach(item => {
   Item.sequelize.transaction({
      isolationLevel: Sequelize.Transaction.ISOLATION_LEVELS.SERIALIZABLE
   }, t => {

      Item.find({
         where: { name: item.name },
         transaction: t,
      }).then(foundItem => {
         let promise;
         if (! foundItem) {
            promise = Item.create({name: item.name, availableSizes: [item.size]});
         }
         else {
            promise = item.update({ availableSizes: [... foundItem.availableSizes, item.size]});
        }
        promise.then(() => {
            ...do stuff
        })
      })
   })
});
```

However, this code throws the following error:

```
Could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions
```

I understand that this error is thrown because the transactions for both sizes of item "a" read the inital state of the database and both try to create a new entry for "a" with conflicting values for the availableSizes field. Therefore I tried the following code:

```js
...
for(const item of items) {
   await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      Item.sequelize.transaction(t => {
         return Item.findOne({
            where: { name: item.name },
            transaction: t,
         }).then(foundItem => {
            let promise;
            if (! foundItem) {
               promise = Item.create({name: item.name, availableSizes: [item.size]});
            }
            else {
               promise = item.update({ availableSizes: [... foundItem.availableSizes, item.size]});
            }
            promise.then(() => {
               resolve()
            });
         });
      });
   });
}
...
```

However, this code will create a database entry for each single size of an item:

```js
{
   id: 1,
   name: "a",
   availableSizes: [1]
},
{
   id: 2,
   name: "a",
   availableSizes: [2]
},
{
   id: 3,
   name: "b",
   availableSizes: [1]
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish the behaviour described above?

Comment: Isn't it because you run the `create` or `update` queries outside of the transaction?
Why don't you `item.update({...},{transaction:t});`

Comment: @Adam You are right, thanks! However, this only fixes my second approach and not the first one. Setting isolation level to SERIALIZABLE still produces the same error. Is there a cleaner and more performant implementation than awaiting each promise in the for-loop?